# c++ objects array remove one

Tags: c++, arrays

I've the following array of Animal objects.

```
Animal animalsArray = new Animal[maxSize];
int actualSize = 0;
```

I use my function to insert there objects ->

```
void AnimalCatalog::Insert(const Animal& animal) {
   if(actualSize <= maxSize) {
      animalsArray[actualSize] = animal;
      actualSize++;
   }
}
```

And my question is how now I can delete any object from it using my function below ?

```
void AnimalsCatalog::Delete(const char *animalName) {
    int index = find(animalName);
    < what to write here >
}

find() is my function which return index of the object from the 
animalsArray
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @水飲み鳥 can you write your code for this function here ?

Comment: @jorge - The solution is rather simple. Scrap all that, and use `std::vector`.

Comment: I would expect most people here can do that. However we are not supposed to do homework if you did not make an attempt.

Comment: @StoryTeller can you write here your proposition ?

Comment: @drescherjm believe or not, I've tried much times but always any error...

Comment: Show your code for that function. We can help fix it. That is one point of this site. Fixing your code not writing code for you. You did not post the broken implementation.

Comment: we can help with errors @jorge

Comment: Not much more to my proposal. Here's the API of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @jorge look up vectors in C++. This would fall into the category of basics, you will find your answers with a bit of searching and reading. Function names are as intuitive as "push_back" and "erase".

Comment: For `std::vector` erase would be the function to use: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: @StoryTeller but is any other solution than using vector, if I've to use arrays 
?

Comment: If you add your code for AnimalsCatalog::Delete() we can help.

Comment: Not any solution you'll likely use in real code

Comment: @drescherjm what can I put it there if I don't know how to achieve this deleteing here ?

Comment: So I just write it here ...

Comment: @StoryTeller Would calling the destructor `~Animal()` explicitly for the element-to-be-deleted turn into an open season for UB?

Comment: Loop through your array till you find the value you want to delete. Delete it, After that move the rest of the items over 1 index. And reduce size.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 - Yes. The `new` expression initialized `maxSize` objects. And `delete[]` will destroy just as many.

Comment: @drescherjm ok, i've tried it, but I don't know how all the rest elements move by one place left ?

Comment: animalsArray[i] = animalsArray[i+1]; loop until i == size-2

Comment: I thought about it, is it good ?
for(int i=0;i<animalsCatalogSize;i++) {
            animalsArray[indexLookingObject] = contacts[indexLookingObject+1];
            animalsArray[i] = animalsArray[i+1];
        }

Answer (score 0):

You will copy from index +1 through actual size +1 to index through actual size and then reduce actual size by 1.

Also, the following test will allow your program to overflow the array bounds:

```
if(actualSize <= maxSize) {
```

Make the test < rather than <=.

Comment: Thx, can you help me with function to delete object from the array here ? I've started implement it but I got stuck in...

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(animalsArray + index + 1,
          animalsArray + actualSize,
          animalsArray + index);
--actualSize;
```